# What is diffrence between Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.iOS(Classic) shown while creating a Portable Class Library?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

While creating a portable class library, its showing xamarin.ios and xamarin.ios(classic). What is the difference ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classic is Xamarin's original API for iOS, also known as `MonoTouch`  (`monotouch.dll`). Its API is deprecated in favor of the "Unified" API  (`Xamarin.iOS.dll`) that combines as much of the iOS, tvOS, Watch and macOS APIs into a *unified* API as possible and supports 32bit and 64bit in the same binary. Classic-based apps should be ported to the unified API (see link below for details)

> Classic Profile Deprecation: As new platforms are added in Xamarin.iOS we are starting to gradually deprecate features from the classic profile (monotouch.dll). For example, the non-NRC (new-ref-count) option was removed. NRC has always been enabled for all unified applications (i.e. non-NRC was never an option) and has no known issues. Future releases will remove the option of using Boehm as the garbage collector. This was also an option never available to unified applications. The complete removal of classic support is scheduled for next fall with the release of Xamarin.iOS 10.0.

re: [Xamarin.iOS Unified](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/unified/)

While Portable Class Libraries (PCL) still work, you should be creating/using .Net Standard 2.0 based libraries for new projects as PCLs are deprecated and their creation has been removed from the latest version of Visual Studio 2017.